# Cannot add a PRIMARY KEY column

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have 2 classes one called `MainWindowViewModel` & one called `Budget`. I have a MainPage.xaml that stores my whole UI for the app.

I'm having an issue with setting a primary key in my `Budget` class. I have created 2 seperate connections to SQLite one called `conn` & the other called `bud`. When my App runs it instantly throws an exception on `OnAppearing()` saying cannot add a primary key to `Budget`. `OnAppearing`
Just shows information the user has saved to a listview.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
                {
                    conn.CreateTable<MainWindowViewModel>();
                    var APRS = conn.Table<MainWindowViewModel>().ToList();
                    APRListView.ItemsSource = APRS;
                }

            using (SQLiteConnection bud = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
                {
                    bud.CreateTable<Budget>();
                    var Budgets = bud.Table<Budget>().ToList();
                    BudgetListView.ItemsSource = Budgets;
                }
        }
```

Below is my App.Xaml.cs

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }

        public App(string filePath)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();

            FilePath = filePath;
        }
```

code for Budget below...

```
using System;
using SQLite;


namespace APRooved.ViewModels
{


    public class Budget : ViewBaseModel
    {

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Budget_ID { get; set; }


        public string BudgetInstanceText 
        {

            get
            {
                return OutgoingProductName;
            }
        }

        public string BudgetInstanceDetail
        {

            get
            {
                return "Monthly Cost: £" + OutgoingMonthlyCostS;
            }
        }

        private string outgoingProductName { get; set; }
        public string OutgoingProductName
        {
            get => outgoingProductName;
            set
            {
                outgoingProductName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OutgoingProductName");
            }
        }


        private decimal outgoingMonthlyCost { get; set; }
        public decimal OutgoingMonthlyCost
        {
            get => outgoingMonthlyCost;
            set
            {

                outgoingMonthlyCost = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("outgoingMonthlyCost");
                outgoingMonthlyCostFin();
            }

        }

        private string outgoingMonthlyCostS { get; set; }
        public string OutgoingMonthlyCostS
        {
            get => outgoingMonthlyCostS;
            set
            {

                outgoingMonthlyCostS = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("outgoingMonthlyCostS");
            }

        }


        public void outgoingMonthlyCostFin()
        {

            outgoingMonthlyCostS = outgoingMonthlyCost.ToString();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: there should be no need for two different connections.  And if the error is clearly in your `Budget` class why have you not posted that code?

Comment: The class is fine its the connection thats not (To my knowledge)

Comment: if you delete your app from the device/emulator and run it, does it work?

Comment: @Jason no, I've now tried the same connection name conn. The app wil now load up but whenever I click the remove button it throws the exception "Budget does not have a primary key"

Comment: again, please show the code for `Budget`.

Comment: @Jason Updated.

Comment: the most likely cause is that Budget already exists without a PK column, and it is unable to modify the existing table.  Deleting the app should fix that, but you could also try renaming the Budget class to Budget2 to test that theory.

Comment: @Jason Perfect mate it was. I previously done that when you said but never worked must have been an issue with my emulator. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most likely cause is that `Budget` already exists without a PK column, and it is unable to modify the existing table. Deleting the app should fix that, but you could also try renaming the `Budget` class to `Budget2` to test that theory.